# Week Number of Date in Between Two Dates

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Example calendar:

```
June
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 Week 1 
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 Week 2 
26 27 28 29 30 1  2  Week 3 
               July
```

And 2 dates:

Start Date: 12 June

End Date : 2 July

How do I get the week number by passing a date?

Ex:

```
weekNum(new Date(2017, 6, 12)) returns 1
weekNum(new Date(2017, 6, 18)) returns 1
weekNum(new Date(2017, 6, 26)) returns 3
weekNum(new Date(2017, 6, 2)) returns 3
```

I've done the calculation of weeks in between and stuck

```
function weeksBetween(d1, d2) {
    return Math.round((d2 - d1) / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the real number of week with momentjs library, it could be useful:

```
moment("12-06-2017", "DD-MM-YYYY").week();
```

docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this should make some sense, and help you with your code :)

```js
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
  var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
}

document.write('<br>D1 - 01st June 2017: ' + new Date(2017, 6, 1).getWeek());
document.write('<br>D2 - 26th June 2017: ' + new Date(2017, 6, 26).getWeek());

var weeksBetween = new Date(2017, 6, 26).getWeek() - new Date(2017, 6, 01).getWeek();
document.write('<br><br>Weeks between D1 and D2: ' + weeksBetween);
```